# creating controls(comboBox etc.) inside of a loop

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I want to create a loop to add comboboxes and labels to a windows form. The cade I have create's them but how do I access them to get the vlues from the comboboxs

```
while (i < 3)
{
    cboTwinRoom = new ComboBox();
    cboTwinRoom.FormattingEnabled = true;
    cboTwinRoom.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(446, 218 + spacer);
    cboTwinRoom.Name = "name" + i;
    cboTwinRoom.Items.AddRange(new object[] {
    "1",
    "2",
    "3",
    "4",
    "5",
    "6",
    "7",
    "8",
    "9"});
    cboTwinRoom.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(45, 21);
    cboTwinRoom.TabIndex = 3;
    grpAvailability.Controls.Add(cboTwinRoom);
    i++;
    spacer = spacer + 50;
}
```

I have tryed using an array to set the names of the comboBox but i get an error. I would be great if anyone can help. Thanks in advance

Error: A local variable named 'names' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'names', which is already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else

Comment: This code doesn't work? What is the error you talking about?

Comment: I don't see any `names` in your code..

Comment: I am asking how can I access the value selected of each comboBox? The error is when I tryed to used a array to set the names of the comboBoxes.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: As you create the ComboBoxes, add them to a List<ComboBox> declared at Form level.

Answer (score 0):

The line cboTwinRoom.Name = "name" + i should not work.You cant concatenate a string to an int.
use "name" + i.ToString()

Answer (score 0):

Try storing the combo boxes as a class-level variable.

First define this:

```
private List<ComboBox> comboBoxes;
```

Then your code could look like this:

```
Func<int, ComboBox> createComboBox = i =>
{
    cb = new ComboBox();
    cb.FormattingEnabled = true;
    cb.Location = new Point(446, 218 + i * 50);
    cb.Name = "name" + i;
    cb.Items.AddRange(new object[]
    {
        "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"
    });
    cb.Size = new Size(45, 21);
    cb.TabIndex = 3;
    return cb;
};

comboBoxes =
    Enumerable
        .Range(0, 3)
        .Select(n => createComboBox(n))
        .ToList();

comboBoxes
    .ForEach(cb => 
        grpAvailability.Controls.Add(cb));
```

I've separated out each of the parts of your code to, hopefully, make it easy to see what each part is doing.